# react-native-svg-charts animate does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to know how to animate chart on react native iOS when I'm using `react-native-svg-charts` or if someone can help me to find another library chart with visualization data.
I tried to use the `animate` prop of the `StackedAreaChart` but it has no results!

Here is my code :

```
export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'react chart',
  };

  render() {

      const data = [
          {
              month: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
              apples: 3840,
              bananas: 1920,
              cherries: 960,
              dates: 400,
          },
          {
              month: new Date(2015, 1, 1),
              apples: 1600,
              bananas: 1440,
              cherries: 960,
              dates: 400,
          },
          {
              month: new Date(2015, 2, 1),
              apples: 640,
              bananas: 960,
              cherries: 3640,
              dates: 400,
          },
          {
              month: new Date(2015, 3, 1),
              apples: 3320,
              bananas: 480,
              cherries: 640,
              dates: 400,
          },
      ]

      const colors = [ 'green', '#aa00ff', 'red', 'yellow' ]
      const keys   = [ 'apples', 'bananas', 'cherries', 'dates' ]
      const svgs = [
                  { onPress: () => console.log('apples') },
                  { onPress: () => console.log('bananas') },
                  { onPress: () => console.log('cherries') },
                  { onPress: () => console.log('dates') },
              ]

      return (
          <StackedAreaChart
              style={ { height: 200, paddingVertical: 16 } }
              data={ data }
              keys={ keys }
              colors={ colors }
              curve={ shape.curveNatural }
              showGrid={ false }
              svgs={ svgs }
              animate={true}
              animationDuration={300}
          />
      )
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by **animate chart**? The `animate={true}` will have effect if you change the data!

Let's see that with an example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { LineChart } from "react-native-svg-charts";

class TestingCharts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          a: 3840
        },
        {
          b: 1920
        },
        {
          c: 960
        },
        {
          d: 400
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    newData = [
      {
        a: 2000
      },
      {
        b: 4902
      },
      {
        c: 325
      },
      {
        d: 7812
      }
    ];

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "stretch"
          }}
        >
          <LineChart
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignSelf: "stretch",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
              margin: 10
            }}
            data={this.state.data}
            svg={{
              strokeWidth: 2,
              stroke: Colors.WHITE
            }}
            animate
          />
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "stretch"
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              alignSelf: "stretch"
            }}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ data: newData })}
          >
            <Text>Change Data!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TestingCharts;
```

### UPDATE

As you mentioned in the comments, you want that chart start with an straight line then it animate to new data:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { LineChart } from "react-native-svg-charts";

class TestingCharts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          a: 0
        },
        {
          b: 0
        },
        {
          c: 0
        },
        {
          d: 0
        }
      ]
    };

    this.changeData();
  }

  changeData() {
    newData = [
      {
        a: 2000
      },
      {
        b: 4902
      },
      {
        c: 325
      },
      {
        d: 7812
      }
    ];

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data: newData });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "stretch"
          }}
        >
          <LineChart
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignSelf: "stretch",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
              margin: 10
            }}
            data={this.state.data}
            svg={{
              strokeWidth: 2,
              stroke: Colors.WHITE
            }}
            animate
          />
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "stretch"
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              alignSelf: "stretch"
            }}
          >
            <Text>My Beautiful Chart :D</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TestingCharts;
```

Consider that you can change the duration of timeout from `1000` to any number in milliseconds!

Comment: thanks for your help! in fact, I want to make an animation of each graph when loading. Kind at the beginning everything is flat and it goes up. and also be able to display data on the graphic when you press on the graph.

Comment: it works on barchart but if i try with another, it doesn't

Comment: <AreaChart
                                 key={index}
                                 style={ StyleSheet.absoluteFill }
                                 data={ item.data }
                                 svg={item.svg}
                                 contentInset={ { top: 20, bottom: 20 } }
         curve={ shape.curveNatural }         
         animate
         animationDuration={500}
                                 >
                             </AreaChart>

Comment: You mean: 1. Start chart with an straight line then it animates to the real data? 2. You want to change data when you click on it?

Comment: I updated my answer! If this is what you want, please vote this up for further references!